# sudo mysql -u root -> Access denied

Tags: permissions, mysql

I have just install mysql and set my local password to something very simple. I was warned that this password was too simple, but I clicked ignore as I wanted it to be simple.

I am now receiving the following:

```
hutber@laptop:~$ sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How can I get access to mysql?

Comment: Try `sudo mysql -u root -p`

Answer (score 1):

The key part is "using password: NO". You need to provide a password:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

and enter the password you set MySQL up with during installation.

---

Workaround in case you do not know it:

```
sudo -i
```

insert the admin password and then do

```
mysql
```

It will allow you to set a user if wanted and a password through the MySQL command line.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work`hutber@laptop:~$ sudo -i
[sudo] password for hutber:        
root@laptop:~# mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
root@laptop:~# 
`

Comment: Also using `sudo mysql -u root -p` s something I tried and the password that I set during installation did not work here.